# Как переопределить gettext(), _()?

Tags: php, gettext

Подскажите, как можно переопределить `gettext()` и синоним `_()`?

Нужно подружить `gettext()` c БД.

```
namespace mySpace;
function gettext($arg) {
    //тут чего-нить делаем с аргументами, например
    $arg.="!";
    return \gettext($arg);
}

echo gettext("Hello");
```

Comment: namespace ?

Comment: пример покажите, пожалуйста

Comment: http://ideone.com/GMBAEZ